# Vertical annotation google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization, vertical-alignment, break

my chart looks like this [img](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yr8o1fa6m0fwxfc/graf.PNG?dl=0)
and my options like this

```
var options =
{
    height:'100%',
    width: '100%',
    legend: {position:'top'},
    title: 'Celkový součet jednotlivých deficitů k roku 2015',
    bars: 'vertical',
    bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
    colors: ['#0079C1'],
    vAxis:
    {
        title:'Počet',
        format: 'decimal'
    },
    hAxis:
    {
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 25,
        title:'Deficit'
    },
    bars: 'vertical',

    annotations: {
        textStyle: {
            color: '#000'
        },
        alwaysOutside: true,
        style:'point'
    },
    chartArea: {
        height: '60%'
    }
};
```

My question is, can you rotate the annotation text verticaly so it doesn't get in the way of others if not is it possible to centre the annotation text to its column?

Another question is regarded to the hAxis you can see that my labels are quite long a i would prefer if some of the long labels broke into half and created a two line label.

Thank you very much for your responses nad sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your English is more than good enough.

Comment: Oh thank you good man

Comment: Did you find an answer for vertical annotation text? I am searching for it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the annotated text vertical by including `annotations: {style: Line}` in the chart options. This is shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachelis/b5o8cuag/). However, I haven't (yet) discovered how to center the annotations on the vertical bars.